# Наслоение грид ячеек

Tags: html, css3, css-grid

Осваиваю грид систему CSS столкнулся с таким непониманием:

```css
.page_blog {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.blog_list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 25px;
  grid-auto-rows: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}

.blog_list__item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: $bg_colorItem;
}

///// Blog Post
.blog_post {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.blog_images {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.blog_images__img {
  object-fit: contain;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.blog_post__inner {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.blog_post__title {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.blog_post__text {
  color: $color_text1;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.buttons_group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
}

.post_watchComments {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 18px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.post_ratingPost {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}

.post_time {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 18px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.blog_quate {
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  color: #fff;
}

.blog_quate__inner {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  text-indent: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.blog_quate__autor {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.blog_list__link {
  display: block;
}

.blog_list__figure {
  margin: 0;
}

.blog_list__img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.blog_list__desc {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page_blog">
  <ul class="blog_list">
    <li class="blog_list__item">


      <article class="blog_post">
        <div class="blog_images">
          <img class="blog_images__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/294x230" alt="images1">
          <img class="blog_images__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/294x230" alt="images2">
        </div>
        <div class="blog_post__inner">
          <h2 class="blog_post__title">Title2</h2>
          <p class="blog_post__text">A man who works with his hands is a laborer; a man who works with his hand s and his brain is a craftsman; but a man who works with his hands and his brain and his heart is an artist...
          </p>
          <div class="buttons_group">
            <span class="post_watchComments">3 comments</span>
            <span class="post_ratingPost">4.7</span>
            <time class="post_time" datetime="2011-11">November, 2011</time>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>


    </li>

    <li class="blog_list__item">
      <div class="blog_quate">
        <blockquote class="blog_quate__inner" cite="autorName">
          <p>If I die even tomorrow, I don't care. I managed to do absolutely everything</p>

          <p class="blog_quate__autor">Freddie Mercury<span>"Queen"</span></p>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="blog_list__item">
      <a class="blog_list__link" href="#">
        <figure class="blog_list__figure">
          <img class="blog_list__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x430" alt="images" />
          <figcaption class="blog_list__desc">Rock Booze</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </li>


    <li class="blog_list__item">
      <article class="blog_post">
        <img class="blog_images__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/294x230" alt="images1">
        <div class="blog_post__inner">
          <h2 class="blog_post__title">Title3</h2>
          <p class="blog_post__text">A man who works with his hands is a laborer; a man who works with his hand s and his brain is a craftsman; but a Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus nulla omnis optio pariatur, quibusdam saepe! Lorem ipsum dolor
            sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, soluta!</p>
          <div class="buttons_group">
            <span class="post_watchComments">3 comments</span>
            <span class="post_ratingPost">4.7</span>
            <time class="post_time" datetime="2011-11">November, 2011</time>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>


    <li class="blog_list__item">
      <div class="blog_quate">
        <blockquote class="blog_quate__inner" cite="autorName">
          <p>If I die even tomorrow, I don't care. I managed to do absolutely everything</p>

          <p class="blog_quate__autor">Freddie Mercury<span>"Queen"</span></p>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="blog_list__item">
      <article class="blog_post">
        <img class="blog_images__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/294x230" alt="images1">
        <div class="blog_post__inner">
          <h2 class="blog_post__title">Title3</h2>
          <p class="blog_post__text">A man who works with his hands is a laborer; a man who works with his hand s and his brain is a craftsman; but a Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectonsetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus nulla omnis optio pariatur, quibusdam saepe! Lorem ipsum dolor
            sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, soluta!</p>
          <div class="butt_group">
            <span class="post_watchComments">3 comments</span>
            <span class="post_ratingPost">4.7</span>
            <time class="post_time" datetime="2011-11">November, 2011</time>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>


    <li class="blog_list__item">
      <article class="blog_post">
        <div class="blog_images">
          <img class="blog_images__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/294x230" alt="images1">
          <img class="blog_images__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/294x230" alt="images2">
        </div>
        <div class="blog_post__inner">
          <h2 class="blog_post__title">Title2</h2>
          <p class="blog_post__text">A man who works with his hands is a laborer; a man who works with his hand s and his brain is a craftsman; but a man who works with his hands and his brain and his heart is an artist...
          </p>
          <div class="buttons_group">
            <span class="post_watchComments">3 comments</span>
            <span class="post_ratingPost">4.7</span>
            <time class="post_time" datetime="2011-11">November, 2011</time>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Почему элементы после 4-го, наслаиваются на верхние элементы, как этого избежать ? 
(Без фиксирования высоты элемента). Необходимо, чтоб пятый элемент занимал место под первым на расстоянии 20рх сверху? (Откуда берется `grid-auto-rows: 20px` )
Пытаюсь сделать верстку для блога, где нету привязанности к длине статьи.

[image: Грид верстка]

Comment: https://masonry.desandro.com/ пользуйтесь масонри сеткой и не парьтесь. Хотя если кто то напишет решение на чистом css будет интересно посмотреть

Comment: Интересно, можно ли обойти данный js костыль новыми возможностями css ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Накладка происходит из-за `grid-auto-rows: 20px;` - оно не для отступа предназначено.
Без этого свойства все по идее правильно, но блоки становятся одинаковой высоты и не прилипают друг к другу плотно.

Возможно, для вашей задачи подойдет вовсе не грид, а многоколоночная верстка: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ydjjgq

Comment: спасибо, не знал про свойство  column-break-inside: avoid;

Comment: * break-inside: avoid; https://caniuse.com/#search=break-inside Правда, поддержка у него какая-то странная, но работает, что хорошо